# How to read the values in json if there is a dash(-) in keys using powershell

Tags: json, powershell

Given this Json:

```
{
 “StudentInfo":{
   “first-name": “xyz",
   “Student_id": "123-xyz"
 }
}
```

I could read the value for student_id using the code below.

```
$config = Get-Content -Raw $Config
$configObject = ConvertFrom-Json –InputObject $config
$StudentId = $configObject.StudentInfo.Student_id
```

However, I am unable to read the value for "first-name" as powershell is treating it to be a command instead of variable.Changing key name is not an option for me.

How can we retrieve the value for "first-name" using powershell 5.1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use quotes:

```
$configObject.StudentInfo.'first-name'
```